# How to find the device is Galaxy Note programmatically?

Tags: android, model

I would like to find whether the given running device is *Galaxy Note* programmatically. How can I do this, kindly help me with a snippet to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get android device name you have to add only a single line of code:

```
android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Copy and paste the following code in your projects onCreate():

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;
tv1.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

android.os.Build.MODEL;

```
String deviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```